# Converting two string fields into datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access-2003

I got two fields(text) in ms access 2003: EventD and EventT. How to concat these two fields and convert them to a single datetime field EventDT with format like this (DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS).

I have looked into other threads but no one has the code format for the one i wanted.

Thanks all

Regards,
10e5x

Comment: what is the format of data in those two columns?

Comment: Both is text type. EventD : 30/04/2012   EventT: 22:10:43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DateSerial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx05d0c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [TimeSerial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws25fd2z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) functions.You can add DateSerail() + TimeSerial() to get the DateTime value

You will have to extract different parts of dates and times from you string values using Mid function and cast them to INT using Val.

The resulting function will be like this:

```
SELECT
DateSerial(Val(Mid(EventD,7,4)), Val(Mid(EventD,4,2)), Val(Mid(EventD,1,2))) + TimeSerail(Val(Mid(EventT,1,2)), Val(Mid(EventT,4,2)), Val(Mid(EventT,7,2))) As DateTimeValue
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Hi DateSerial and TimeSerial are undefined functions. I am using ms access 2003. btw thanks for replying.